# Блок выходящий за пределы родителя

Tags: html, css

В общем все вроде просто. Есть родитель, его ширина `800px`. У него есть родитель, его ширина `150%` ширины родителя так что он выходит за его пределы. Все работает нормально до тех пор пока не сузить окзно браузера. Из-за `margin-left: 25%` блок обрезается слева правильно выходя за пределы окна, но справа у него остается несимметричный отрезок. Так есть это можно исправить добавляя `overflow:hidden` к родителю с шириной `100%`, но это не подойдет из-за проблемы если сузить еще сильнее то нет скрола по основному контенту так же.

Я создал пример на JSFiddle потому-то там можно поиграть с размером вьюпорта. Попробуйте его увеличить и сузить, потом попробуйте добавить `overflow:hidden` к `.body`.

https://jsfiddle.net/m6op1dwt/11/

Я полагаю все-равно может быть что-то непонятно, я отвечу на все вопросы. 
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Не очень понятно зачем `margin-left:25%;` и `width:150%;`

Comment: У вас ширина статичная (800px)

Comment: покажите что вы хотите в резльтате, нарисуйте

Comment: @Duoxx 150% ибо этот блок должен быть на 50% шире родителя. `margin-left:25%;` ибо (150%-100%)/2 = 25%, так есть половина ширины выходящей за пределы родителя. Ширина и должна бысть статичной, но когда окно блаузера слишком узкое должен появляться горизонтальный скролл бар, но при этом ломается прогресс бар изза причины выше. То что на фидле и есть то что я хочу сделать, мне попросту нужно придумать как заставить блок всегда отображать столько же справа сколько слева от своего родителя.

Comment: Просто попробуйте сузить окно и увидите как появляется горизонтальный скролл бар, прокрутите вправо и увидите что прогресс бар справа длиннее чем слева.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно не допускать ситуаций, когда дочерний элемент больше родителя. Но ситуации бывают разные. Вот способ с абсолютным позиционированием:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  padding-top:50px;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
}
.progress{
  border:1px solid;
  width:150%;   
  max-width:100vw; /*Ограничиваем ширину прогресс-бара шириной экрана*/
  height:30px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;  
  left:50%; /*смещаем прогресс-бар влево на 50% ширины родителя*/
  transform:translateX(-50%); /*смещаем прогресс-бар вправо на 50% своей ширины, тем самым центрируя его относительно родителя*/
}
.progress__bar{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#cda;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__bar"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе.</p>
</div>
```

Вариант с изменением разметки(более корректный, на мой взгляд)

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.progress{
  max-width:1600px;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border:1px solid;
}
.progress__bar{
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background-color:#cda;
}
.container{
  max-width:800px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress__bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе.</div>
```

Comment: Вообще я застрял на том что я хотел исправить свой вариант, так как меня не интересовала адаптивность на данном этапе. Я так же на этом портале ранее встречал людей которые строго утверждали мне что это целиком нормально выводить блок за пределы родителя(что я тоже считал не крайне правильным). В целом проект только в начале разработки, изменения добавить не сложно. Но меня все же интересует ответ на: `transform:translateX(-50%);` ведь может размывать контент блока который двигает, верно? У меня прямо чуйка что этот вариант сделает мне что-то плохое, явно в чем-то подвох.

Comment: Не, `translate` просто двигает элемент, не изменяя его размеров. У других tranform-свойств, изменяющих размеры или форму элемента такой эффект есть, да.

Comment: возможно когда отступ только с одной стороны то не видно. Но я вспомнил что я создавал ранее сайт, там был отступ сверху и слева и таки текст размывался. В целом спасибо, я оставил этот вопрос в гневе на себя и получил исчерпывающий ответ.